# C - Insert rows and columns into a 2d Array

Tags: c, mpi

Saying that I have an `n x n` array that I declared like this:

```
int **matrix = malloc(n * sizeof *matrix);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof **matrix);
```

At some point doing some measurements, I would like to add an extra line and column, like after the second row and column. I would like to add a 2.3 row and column ( between 2.2, 3.2, 2.3, 3.3). So I would like to go from an already set `n x n` array (set with numbers etc), to a `n+1 x n+1` array, with the extra line and row somewhere in the middle of the array, not in the end.

P.S. If you are curious, I am trying to implement the hierarchical agglomerative clustering algorithm where I have to increment the similarity matrix with the new merged cluster and redo the similarity calculations all over again.

---Edit with more info on my problem, cause I am in need for help---

This `n x n` array is used for the similarities of `n` entities. For example, n points on a coordinates system, n document files, n images etc. This algorithm that I am trying to implement merges two of each of these files together creating a new file or a cluster. So in each iteration there will be a new cluster (and frankly two previous clusters will be merged, so there will be no use of them) that needs to be checked for similarities with the rest of the remaining clusters/files. This procedure stops when there is a whole cluster, or a given number of clusters. Anyway, I hope you get the picture.

Comment: You can resize a dynamic array with `realloc()`.

Comment: I see, but what happens to the data that are stored into the array?

Comment: When accessing elements of the matrix, do you need to access by index or do you normalcy just iterate through them?

Comment: @harmic since a new cluster is made, i will have to go through all the data, the new cluster included, to find the new similarities. Actually the only thing i have to do is test the similarities of all the clusters with the new one only.

Answer (score 3):

Inserting a row in the middle requires the following steps:

1. Allocate a new memory region large enough to hold the expanded row size
2. Loop through the old array. Up until the insertion point, just copy the value from the old array. When you reach the insertion point, add the pointer to the new row (which you also need to allocate). Then proceed to copy the remaining entries from the original array.
3. Free the original outer array.

Note that I did not say to use realloc. You can do that but it would result in some of the elements getting copied twice, unnecessarily.

To inner a column, you need to use the same process for each of the row arrays.

Note that insertion into the middle of an array is an expensive operation, particularly in the case of adding a column to a 2d array. If it happens often and the array is large you should consider switching to a different data structure.

Comment: I don't know what i was trying to find. This is crearly not the best way to do it. However thanks for the tip. Hopefully i will come up with some simpler solution. I am keeping it as unsolved for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Realloc is the way to do so. Realloc function in C takes two arguments, one is pointer to current memory block and the other is the new size. Realloc returns a pointer only to the newely created memory. So to say

```
int *i = realloc(matrix[i], (PreviousLength + 1) * sizeof(int));
PreviousLength += 1;
```

The int `i` will now only contain your new Integer; therefore can be set instantly to some value of choice.

Remember that Realloc is used when you've previously used Malloc or Calloc, not when using a new. If you ever will be.
The above example would add another column to the row [i]

Find more information [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the already-existing answers: use realloc to expand the size of your array. Then the extra memory will be conceptually "at the end" of the new array/pointer, after the previously-filled stuff. If you want to insert things in between previously-existing stuff, you'd need to move array contents around by yourself.